# jquery select all and enable area WORKING

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I can enable and check all the fields on my form, but I can't have the fields enabled automatically!
This is my code (now working):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#lnk_checkall").click(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("checked"))
            {
                $("input:checkbox.fb_chk").attr("checked", "checked");
                $("input:checkbox.fb_chk").trigger("change");
            }
            else
            {
                $("input:checkbox.fb_chk").removeAttr("checked");
                $("input:checkbox.fb_chk").trigger("change");
            }
        });

        $("tr.photo_fb_item .fb_chk").change(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked")
            {
                $("input.d", parent).removeAttr("disabled");
                $("textarea.d", parent).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else
            {
                $("input.d", parent).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("textarea.d", parent).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }

        });

    });
```

and this is my page:

```
                $out .= '<input type="checkbox"  name="checkall" id="checkall">Select All<br>';

                $out .= '<tr class="photo_fb_item">'
                    . '<td><input type="checkbox" class="fb_chk" name="PICSOURCE[]" value="' . $item['source'] . '"/>'
```

can anyone add me the code to check all the boxes, please?

Comment: You have to use `checked` instead of `disabled`. Also, `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: I need a new function that will check all my checkboxes when I select the "select all" checkbox..

Comment: needs more clarity what are the fields that need to be enabled on any condition? and the code does not contain the textarea with class "d"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).prop("checked", true);
```

should be able to check your checkbox
for more details on this please refer the following post

[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

## EDIT

code to check all fields if checkall is enabled uncheck otherwise

```
$('#checkall').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('checked')== true) {
    $('.fb_chk').each(function() { 
     $(this).prop("checked", true); 
    }) 
  }
  else {
    $('.fb_chk').each(function() { 
     $(this).prop("checked", false); 
    }) 
  }
 })
```

Comment: I need a new function that will check all my checkboxes when I select the "select all" checkbox...

Comment: add the following code to your Select All checkbox's on click event
  

    `$('#checkall').click(function() {
      $('.fb_chk').each(function() {

       $(this).prop("checked", true);
      })
    })`

that should do the job.

Comment: almost there... now I can check all the checkboxes, but the fields are not automatically enabled... thank you for the help! :)

Comment: if its fixed, kindly mark the question answered as it will help others searching with similar queries

Comment: This answer is quite ready yet. Use `if($(this).prop('checked'))` instead of `if($(this).attr('checked') == true)`. jQuery versions that have `.prop` (1.6+) have `attr('checked') == 'checked'`, not `attr('checked') == true`. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/